# Elasctic Beanstalk platform error on eb create

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm setting up an elastic beanstalk for a node server. When running the '`eb create`' command I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: NotFoundError - Platform Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux does not appear to be valid
```

I can't find much about it online and the node.js running on 64bit is the way my instance is set so I'm not sure why it is marked as invalid.

Comment: Looks like the EBCLI somehow overwrote the platform name in an incorrect form. You can easily fix this by replacing the `default_platform` field in the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file with "node.js", or "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.5 running Node.js". Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @progfan That has worked. Can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark this question as complete? Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks for verifying, @Rafty. BTW, I am curious to know which version of the EBCLI you used/are using.

Comment: @progfan I'm using 'EB CLI 3.12.4 (Python 2.7.1)'. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189387/elasctic-beanstalk-platform-error-on-eb-create?noredirect=1#comments-49189387)): This sounds like a bug in the EBCLI. The EBCLI somehow overwrote the platform name in the .config.yml file in an incorrect form.

You can easily fix this by replacing the `default_platform` field in the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file with "node.js", or "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.5 running Node.js".